# how to display content part in seeddms Fulltext index info

Tags: php

I have installed the seeddms in my local windows xampp server and i done the full text index info and could not find the option to display the contents of the uploaded documents and pdf like in the demo(http://demo.seeddms.org/out/out.IndexInfo.php). I googled it and could not find the relevant answer.

Please give me any suggestions to sort it out.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can enable full text search from Admin tools -> Setting -> [tab] Site -> [checked ] Enable Full text search.